# how to iterate pandas frame from csv and apply text summarisation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, nlp

Im working on text summarization extraction on long text data. I have multiple users text data in the input csv file. But current code is appending all the text column data in to sentences and then apply logic. How do I apply the code for each row instead of merging all the column values? Any Help will appreciated.

**Input.csv (^ delimited)**

```
uid^name^text
36d73f013aa7^Don Howard^The Irvine Foundation has entered into a partnership with College Futures Foundation that starts a new chapter in our support of postsecondary success in California.To achieve Irvine’s singular goal. 
36d73f013aa8^Simon Haris^That’s why we have long provided funding to expand postsecondary success. Now with our focus on low-wage workers, we have decided to split our postsecondary funding into two parts:. Strengthening and expanding work-ready credentialing programs (which we will do directly, primarily as part of our Better Careers initiative). 
36d73f013aa8^David^Accelerating and expanding the attainment of bachelor’s degrees (which we will fund through our partnership with College Futures). We believe that College Futures is in a stronger position than we are to make grants to support improvements in how the CSUs and the California Community Colleges can better serve students.
```

**pseudo code**

```
Loop each record
     apply below logic to text column to get summary
```

**Code : Text Summarization Code**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
nltk.download('punkt') # one time execution
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import re
# Read the CSV file
import io


df = pd.read_csv('/home/sshuser/textsummerisation/input.csv',sep='^')
# split the the text in the articles into sentences
sentences = []
for s in df['text']:
  sentences.append(sent_tokenize(s))
  
# flatten the list
sentences = [y for x in sentences for y in x]

# remove punctuations, numbers and special characters
clean_sentences = pd.Series(sentences).str.replace("[^a-zA-Z]", " ")

# make alphabets lowercase
clean_sentences = [s.lower() for s in clean_sentences]

nltk.download('stopwords')# one time execution

stop_words = stopwords.words('english')

def remove_stopwords(sen):
  sen_new = " ".join([i for i in sen if i not in stop_words])
  return sen_new
  
# remove stopwords from the sentences
clean_sentences = [remove_stopwords(r.split()) for r in clean_sentences]

# Extract word vectors
word_embeddings = {}
fopen = open('/home/sshuser/textsummerisation/glove.6B.100d.txt', encoding='utf-8')
for line in fopen:
    values = line.split()
    word = values[0]
    print(values)
    print(word) 
    coefs = np.asarray(values[1:], dtype='float32')
    word_embeddings[word] = coefs
fopen.close()

sentence_vectors = []
for i in clean_sentences:
  if len(i) != 0:
    v = sum([word_embeddings.get(w, np.zeros((100,))) for w in i.split()])/(len(i.split())+0.001)
  else:
    v = np.zeros((100,))
  sentence_vectors.append(v)

len(sentence_vectors)

# similarity matrix
sim_mat = np.zeros([len(sentences), len(sentences)])

for i in range(len(sentences)):
  for j in range(len(sentences)):
    if i != j:
      sim_mat[i][j] = cosine_similarity(sentence_vectors[i].reshape(1,100), sentence_vectors[j].reshape(1,100))[0,0]
      
import networkx as nx

nx_graph = nx.from_numpy_array(sim_mat)
scores = nx.pagerank(nx_graph)

ranked_sentences = sorted(((scores[i],s) for i,s in enumerate(sentences)), reverse=True)

# Specify number of sentences to form the summary
sn = 10

# Generate summary
for i in range(sn):
  print(ranked_sentences[i][1])
```

**Expected output**: Output of the above code should come in summary column for each record

```
uid^name^text^summary
```

Comment: Add a standalone code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: You can reproduce the issue with the given code and input

Comment: @AniketBote Any suggestions?